# Нужно ли ставить тире или нет

Tags: тире

Главное (–) не опускать руки ни при каких обстоятельствах.

После «Главное» тире ставится, но перед «не» – нет. Что тут ставить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ГлАвное – не опускать руки ни при каких обстоятельствах.**

***Главное*** – это **субстантивированное прилагательное в роли подлежащего**, оно выделено паузой, поэтому тире ставится в обязательном порядке, определяя состав подлежащего и сказуемого.

Правило Розенталя относится к тому случаю, когда при отсутствии связки оба главных члена предложения выражены **существительными в именительном падеже**. Кроме того, правило корректируется расстановкой логических ударений.

В приведенном примере **логическое ударение падает на подлежащее,** поэтому после него делается пауза.